# How to use JQuery/JavaScript in SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, cewp

I am new for here and sharepoint. I would like to ask a question regarding Javascript for Sharepoint page. I am sorry if it was asked before.

I have found a script which is called "let-it-snow.min.js". I have added it to SiteAssets. Also I have added "jquery-3.2.1"to same location. As far as I read from the web site, I would be able to snow to my sharepoint webpage..

[image]

After that I have created a script editor on Master Page and I have added the below script code to call the files.

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="../SiteAssets/let-it-snow.min.js"></script>
```

I have also set the Chrome Type to "None". When I save the script which is on the Master Page. Anything happened unfortunately. I guess I did something wrong & there is still missing configuration on the script.

Is there anyone who can help me regarding the problem?

Thanks in advance,
-Burak

Answer (score 0):

Remove “..” from the path to the js scripts.

Just reference as /SiteAssets.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i want to tell you ".." means you are trying to go one level up wherever you are.

"/" means you are in root url

"/sites/yoursitename/SiteAssets/let-it-snow.min.js"
or
"/SiteAssets/let-it-snow.min.js"
if you are in root site.
please let me know in case of any problem.

Comment: Hi Negi,Thank you very much for your message. I didn't know the meaning of "..". I have fixed it as you mentioned as below,  
<script src="/sites/SRTAC/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/sites/SRTAC/SiteAssets/let-it-snow.min.js"></script>   
and
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/let-it-snow.min.js"></script>
But unfortunately the both types of script aren't working :/

Comment: Hi Burak, can you please check you all files is checked in ?

Comment: another option please type full url in src. and hit same url in browser and check it is accessible by another user or not?

Comment: Hi, Yes the both files are checked in before.. If you would like to check the files, I can provide it to you by some way..

Comment: yes burak please provide i will check in ma end will let you know

Comment: also please check www.yoursitename.com/sites/SRTAC/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.js , type this address directly in your browser check are we able to open that file der?

Comment: Hi, You can reach the scripts via http://dosya.co/if5eyngp75is/JS.rar.html
I have checked the address directly in browser and It worked for me. I was able to reach the content via that way.

Comment: can you please send me in my mail id? mukeshsingh.negi007@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

In Browser developer tool,please check if the Js file referenced has been loaded in the page like below:
[image]

And is there any error message in Console ?